# Windows 7 Boot Camp Partition Not Recognizing Full Disk Space

Tags: windows-7, macos, hard-drive, multi-boot, boot-camp

I recently used Boot Camp to install Windows 7 on a small partition on my MBP, and have found the need to extend the partition for more space. Through the use of several tools, I have managed to extend the partition so that my Windows 7 partition is 100GB.

However, when I boot to Windows, it still seems to think that it is only 50GB.

**The following are approximations**

**Windows Disk Management** says: Windows 50GB, OS X 250GB

**GParted** *and* **Paragon Partition Manager** both say: Windows 100GB, OS X 200GB

The third party tools I have are correct, but that really doesn't help me. I've run both `chkdsk /f` and `chkdsk /r` on the drive, but neither fixed the issue. `chkdsk` did however recognize all of the free space on the partition, which is slightly confusing.

Is there a way I can get my Windows 7 install to recognize the extra disk space?

I have a backup of my Windows installation, so if there is a way to restore that into a larger Boot Camp partition, I could work with that as well. Also, I have access to the tools listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used rEFIt to sync the MBR and GPT?

http://refit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried using rEFIt, but I'm getting an error: `NOT FOUND returned from gbtsync.efi` (or something like that). I've researched it a little bit, but I'm not finding any way to get around that...

Comment: It looks as though that may be an issue with rEFIt.. However, some have had success with gptsync using an Ubuntu LiveCD.
These steps taken from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1297229):
`- Grab an Ubuntu live CD and boot
- Install gptsync_0.13-10 or higher from *Debian* packages (Ubuntu doesn't ship it, and the original rEFIt doesn't have the fix (yet?). Download from packages.debian.org and install with dpkg --install
- Run gptsync on the affected disk`