# Boot Camp: Partition error when installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, boot-camp

So I've been trying to install Windows 7 on my Mac (Solid State Drive) with Boot Camp 5.1. Everything goes smoothly until I need to select a partition to install Windows on. The Windows 7 installer complains that it can't install to my Boot Camp partition. It continues to complain even after formatting the partition and deleting the Boot Camp partition, and letting Windows create its own partition in Boot Camp's space.

After exiting the installer in failure, I encounter a 'no boot disk found error' on startup and I have to reset the PRAM to return to OS X.

I'm at a loss at how to proceed. What now?

Comment: never let Windows touch a Mac drive directly - it breaks things, as it doesn't understand how it works. You now have your work cut out to rescue it. See if this might help - http://superuser.com/questions/451192/resizing-bootcamp-partition-without-wiping?lq=1

Comment: I don't quite understand. What needs 'rescuing'? Resetting the PRAM works fine, and I was even able to install Windows 8 (too buggy to use with my USB hub, though).

Answer (score 0):

If you boot from a thumb-drive, for some reason macos won't always boot normal next time around. Hold down the option key during boot and the macos disk will show up as a bootable drive. Just click it.

Comment: Ah, no. I'm having no trouble using OS X, just installing Windows 7. I think it might have something to do with USB 3.0 drivers (my flashdrive is USB 3). I can install Windows 8 without problems, but then my USB hub 'flickers' at a rate that is virtually unusable.